# The automorphism group of a toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a projective toric variety (assume nonsingular, if it helps).  Is there a nice description of its automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$?  I can see that for $\mathbb P^n$ it is $\operatorname{PGL}(n+1)$ but not in other examples.  What about the product of projective spaces?

Comment: You might want to have a look at D. A. Cox, _The homogeneous coordinate ring of a toric variety,_ J. Algebraic Geom. 4 (1995), 17-50.